# How does setting concurrencyLevel in ConcurrentHashMap help if my hashCode() is weak?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrenthashmap

If I declare `ConcurrentHashMap<Person, Interests>`
- If I overrode `Person.hashCode()` to result in same hash value[bad design thou!], so that all elements are placed in the same bucket
- How would default concurrencyLevel[16] help concurrent writes?

My understanding is that in the above case, Map entries are not distributed. Hence, while modifying a particular `<K,V>`, lock is established on the one-and-only-existing hashBucket so no other thread can modify other `<K1,V1>` and benefit from concurrent modifications

Comment: It seems to me that your central assumption is invalid. The Javadoc explicitly states that '`concurrencyLevel` affects internal sizing'.

Comment: how does it affect internal sizing? Say I have 100 elements in my Map and all going into same Bucket. As all elements fall under same segment,  only one thread can modify the Map and rest are blocked.

Answer (score 1):

In `ConcurrentHashMap` write operations could block each other only when they write in the same segment. That said, when your `Person` objects have the same `hashCode()` result, they will all be placed in the same segment of the HashMap.

This means that the additions to the `ConcurrentHashMap` will be synchronized because each time a new `Person` object is added, the lock for the single `LinkedList` in the `ConcurrentHashMap` is acquired and other threads trying to add another `Person` would have to wait.

Comment: May I know how segmentation and internal sizing correlate. If there are 100 elements - evenly distributed [bucket size 1], how would my concurrencyLevel [16] divide into segments - is it 100/16 which is roughly 16elements per segment? Or is the segmentation per bucket?

Comment: The concurrencyLevel actually specifies how many threads can access your collection at a given time. If your concurrency level is 16 and you have 50 threads trying to write to 50 buckets, only 16 threads at most will be able to do so in parallel. The others will wait for a 'slot'. However, if all the 50 threads try to access a single bucket, only one will succeed and the others will wait. The ConcurrencyLevel should be set based on the number of threads you expect to access your collection. If you expect 50 threads, set the ConcurrencyLevel to 50.